# Excel - how do you underline entire cell width not text/number width?

Tags: excel, formatting, number-formatting

How do I underline the entire cell width like so? This was sent to me in another file and I've been copying the format. I'd like to do it myself but I can only get it to underline the text/number width and not the entire cell width like the below pic. Anyone know how?

[image]

EDIT: found it. setting the cell format to accounting does the trick.

Comment: This should be asked on SuperUser as it does not have to do with programming.

Comment: use the border....

Comment: @Sorceri I'm not trying to underline the border... I'm trying to underline the text.

Comment: It using a custom format of `*#0.0` with the underline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## This is one way:

[image: Underline]

Comma style → Decrease Decimal → Underline

Comment: The single-quote button changes it to accounting mode, which (I'm guessing) extends to the underline style.

Comment: It's a comma :-)

Answer (score 2):

Underline, click "Font," and set it to use "single accounting" style.

[image]

Comment: This is the more standard answer you'll find across the web. Worth noting, however, is that numbers will not be reflected in the same way as text *unless* they are changed to accounting format (as seen in the answer provided by @ashleedawg).

Answer (score 0):

Right-click at cell --> Format Cell... --> Font 's tab --> check "normal font" --> click OK

Answer (score -2):

Its the "accounting" number format that allows the underline to work!

Comment: This doesn't seem to add any new information to the already-existing answers. [Check this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write an answer